# Quote/saying to mean "the only worthwhile object of study is Man himself"?

Tags: quotes, popular-refrains

Looking for a known Greek/Roman quote/saying that expresses the opinion why the humanities are the only worthwhile subjects to study.

> Yes, dad.  I know studying Philosophy is a waste of time but as the Ancients said "____".

Something like *the only worthwhile object of study is Man himself*.

Googling around **Greek, study, man** was pretty uninformative, the only result I ended up with was **Protagoras'** `Man is the measure of all things` which means something entirely different.

I originally saw this in a work of fiction, but can't remember the phrase, whether if it was a straight out reference to a known quote or  if it was just paraphrasing what was probably the position of ancient Greek scholars.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [it does not seem to be on topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: 'Man is the measure of all things' is pretty close.

Comment: Alexander Pope: "The proper study of mankind is man," and he may have been quoting the classics. It would be worth posting this, or a similar question, on the Latin Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper study of Mankind is Man. - Alexander Pope - BrainyQuote.

https://www.google.com/search?q=the+proper+study+of+mankind+is+man&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1